# How to separate sulfur and carbon powders?

Tags: home-experiment, extraction

How can someone separate two elemental solids, in powder form, that are mixed together?

If I have a powder, and its mass is 60% carbon and 40% sulfur, how do I separate one from another in a high school level laboratory?

Comment: If it's mixture of two powders - pure sulfur and carbon then flotation is suitable method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Distillation: Sulfur has the comparatively low boiling point of 718 K ​(445 °C). Heating in apparatus not affected by sulfur (which leaves out iron) will leave behind the carbon. [This is, after all, how sulfur winds up at volcanic vents, where it is harvested.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENY6z2pj2pQ) You might even create a retort out of concrete, which would simulate volcanic rock.
2. Sulfur is somewhat soluble in toluene and in carbon disulfide, but both are toxic and flammable, with $\ce{CS2}$ being particularly easy to ignite. These are not safe to use without proper training and equipment.

Comment: Thank's a lot for taking the time to reply, Dr Pippik. It seems distilation is the way to go. What materials would withstand that kind of temperature though? I assume glass is out of considerantion, and, as you said, iron, because it would react with sulphur. What do you think would be an appropriate material for the apparatus?

Comment: You might try making a small retort out of Portland cement, sold in most hardware stores. It would probably fall apart after long use, but might suffice for a demonstration (which I suggest you do *outdoors*,  away from flammable objects, and where breezes will remove the fumes). Borosilicate glass or fused  quartz could be used, but be sure the opening is wide and/or heated, so it does not get plugged with solid sulfur.

Comment: Dr. Pippik, the experiment is not to be actually performed, but computionatilly simulated for the Mojang's game Minecraft. I intend to implement chemistry as a mod in that game (a mod is modification added by users for the enjoyment of other users). Thank you for kindly replying once more. I will be looking at borosilicate glass and fused quartz as the theoretical/modeling materials I will use. This is because portland cement is kind of an issue in another question I made (in that question as a starting point for the making of portland cement, I want to be able to prepare CaO).

Comment: Good luck with the modification! It sounds interesting.

Comment: That's very encouraging to read, thank you for sharing your knowledge with me doctor.